# sed to replace docker image tag in docker-compose

Tags: regex, amazon-ec2, sed, gitlab-ci

We are using GitLab for CI-CD and our applications are run as docker-containers inside EC2 instances and use ECR as the registry. I have a problem with this approach when it comes to the deployment stage. I want `docker-compose.yml` to pick up the image tagged with the current branch from ECR. Hence I use `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` like this :

`sudo docker-compose pull | sed "s/$VERSION/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/g"`

I know the syntax is incorrect and `$VERSION` gets replaced permanently by the branch name. So, when next time I do `sudo docker-compose pull` there's no `$VERSION` to replace & deployment stage will stop.

Our ECR images will have a path like this: `xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ground-zero/x:$VERSION` (inside `docker-compose.yml`)

How to use `sed` correctly to search for `code-ground & :` because they are common for every microservice in the ECR path.